# save a figure with ggplot library to jpg file

Tags: python, pandas, python-ggplot

The GGplot documentation seems to indicate you can save a figure as jpg by using the device paramter, however when I try to use it I get the error: Exception, `

> unknown format jpg.

```
def chart(dataframe, stock_name, title):
    title = str(title)
    name = str(stock_name)
    graph_title = "TYD Chart for " + title
    df = dataframe.set_index('date')
    df = df[(df["stock_name"]==name)].ix['2016/01/01':'2016/02/09']
    ggplot_obj = ggplot(df.reset_index(), aes('date','close')) + geom_line() + ggtitle(graph_title)
    ggsave(filename="/Users/Joshua/Documents/stocks/" + title, device="jpg",plot = ggplot_obj, width = 10, height = 6)
    print ("Saved File for " + str(title))
```

Saved the file to `png` instead using [the tutorial here on GGSAVE](https://stat545-ubc.github.io/block017_write-figure-to-file.html#write-figures-to-file-with-ggsave)

Comment: Note that the tutorial uses ggplot2, the original R version of ggplot and you are using the python version which is incomplete. The easiest way is probably simple setting the filename to something ending in `<name>.jpg`. Although the above version should work, so maybe file a bug at https://github.com/yhat/ggplot. Could even be bug in matplotlib...

Answer (score -2):

Using the tutorial here, [GGSAVE tutorial](https://stat545-ubc.github.io/block017_write-figure-to-file.html#write-figures-to-file-with-ggsave), saved the file as png instead of JPG.

Comment: This answer refers to ggsave in R. The question is about python.